Find common data among two RDD in spark execution
I have  RDD1
col1 col2
A     x123
B     y123
C     z123


RDD2
col1 
A          
C   

I want to run intersection of two RDDs and find common elements i.e. item that are in RDD2 what is the data of these item in RDD1
RDD3 = RDD1  RDD2
RDD3
col1 col2
A     x123
C     z123

Can anyone please suggest how can I do this during my spark execution ??
tried flattening the RDD and comparison but doesn't work

I can think if two ways, intersection and join like below.
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Common Data RDD").getOrCreate()

val seq1 = Seq(("A","x123"),("B","y123"),("C","z123"),("Y",("abc")))
val seq2 = Seq(("A"),("C"), ("D"),("Y"), ("Z"))
val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(seq1)
val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(seq2)

val rdd_temp = rdd2.map(i => (i,"")) /* to make pair rdd*/

//aprach1
val rdd3 =  rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd_temp)
val finalRdd = rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd3)
    finalRdd.foreach(println)

//aprach2
val rdd_joined = rdd1.join(rdd_temp).map((tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2._1)))
rdd_joined.foreach(println)

 // Output 
(A,x123) 
(Y,abc) 
(C,z123)

